# clear multi-level std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

If I have multi-level map like this,

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> myMap;

constructor() {
    std::map<int, int> myInsideMap;

    myInsideMap.insert(std::make_pair(1,2));
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair(1, myInsideMap));
}

destructor() {
    // is this cleared correctly?? recursively?
    myMap.clear();
}
```

I expect myMap.clear() will clear myInsideMap too.
would it be working that I expected?

Comment: Well after the [`clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/clear) call the data in the map `myMap` have been destroyed, so the question is moot actually as the "inner" maps doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: You can easily add debug output to the destructor of contained objects to find out. That said, consider using two ints as key in the map, like `map<pair<int,int>, int>`. My gut feeling is that this is closer to what you want to express actually.

Comment: It  won't clear `myInsideMap`, but it will destroy all the maps it contains. `myInsideMap` is local to the constructor, so it's destroyed when the constructor exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expect myMap.clear() will clear myInsideMap too. would it be working that I expected?

No. `myMap.clear()` will destroy its own *copy* of `myInsideMap`. `myMap` will cease to exist when the `constructor()` scope is exited.

Standard library containers own their elements. When they are cleared or cease to exist, their elements are destroyed too.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting a note from the standard section 23.2.1 that talks about General container requirements:

**the destructor is applied to every element of a; all the memory is deallocated.**

> I expect myMap.clear() will clear myInsideMap too

Nope. myMap clears the contents of mapMap only which includes a std::pair object internally which in turn has a copy of myInsideMap.

myInsideMap was allocated on the stack and hence it is deallocated when its local scope is over when constructor() exits. Again, this is not where the myInsideMap (copy) inside the myMap is destructed.

> is this cleared correctly?? recursively?

Yes, myMap is cleared here but the recursive destruction happens as follows - the std::pair destructor is called internally for which the key and values are destructed. Since, the copy of myInsideMap was the value within this pair structure, that content is also destroyed. So the destructive "recursion" doesn't touch the local or the actual myInsideMap in constructor().

Answer (score -1):

Yes,maps will destruct all components. You may want to read about [destructor for map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/~map/).

Comment: But `myInsideMap` isn't a component of `myMap`, so it won't be cleared.